# How to replace/reset Relay.Environment for RNRF Router

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

When user logs out of the app I want to reset `Relay.Environment` (replace existing one with a new one). 
I've tried passing the new `Relay.Environment` to `Router`, when re-rendering the component, 
`<Router wrapBy={createRenderer()} sceneStyle={styles.scene}>
     <Scene key="root" tabs tabBarStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#333333' }}>`

`createRenderer()` returns current `Relay.Environment

but I still see that scenes created with old `Relay.Environment`.
Is there a correct way to do this? Am I missing something.

Alex

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Relay Classic, there is a [bug](https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/1494) that exposes the old environment instead of the new one after a replacement when accessed via `this.props.relay`. Try accessing the environment via `this._reactInternalInstance._context.relay.environment` to see if it matches your new environment.